# How to create a module in the main class in c++?

Tags: c++, module, scope

I've got a great problem, that may be a newbie one.My problem is that I get an error that the method was not created in this scope, but it really it is.

```
int main() { //beggining main
  int n;
  int m;
  int result =0;
  cout << "Dime m en (m sobre n)" << endl;
  cin >> m;
  cout << "Dime n:" << endl;
  cin >> n; 
  result = calculate(m,n);
  cout << result << endl;
  return 0;
} //finish main

int calculate(int m, int n){ //begin calculate
  return m+n;
} //finish calculate
```

when I build the project, I get ‘calculate’ was not declared in this scope in the result = calculate(m,n); line ;

It may be a silly thing, but why do I get this error? Thanks a lot

Comment: Put it before main or forward declare it.

Answer (score 1):

Forward-declare your `calculate` function like this:

```
int calculate(int m, int n);

int main() { //beginning main
    int n;
    int m;
    int result =0;
    cout << "Dime m en (m sobre n)" << endl;
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Dime n:" << endl;

    cin >> n;
    result = calculate(m,n);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
} //finish main

int calculate(int m, int n){ //begin calculate
    return m+n;
}
```

The reason you have to do this is because in C and C++, the compiler doesn't know that your function exists yet when it comes across the call to `calculate()`.
There are two ways to avoid errors stemming from this behavior: either you define the entire function, with its body, prior to `main` and everything will then be known to the compiler by the time it sees the `calculate()` call, or you simply declare the function using what's called a *prototype*, which declares the name, argument types, and return type of your function, and then define the function body later. The code here takes the latter approach.

Answer (score 1):

**why do I get this error?**

The compiler only knows about what has been declared. At the point it encounters the statement

```
result = calculate(m,n);
```

in your `int main()` function, it has not come across a declaration of `calculate` that fits the usage (or any in this case), hence your program is faulty.

So, you must tell the compiler about your function `calculate()` *before* you use it. This may either by moving the definition of `calculate()` in front of that of `main()`, or by merely adding a declaration, telling the compiler that such a function exists, and providing its body later, as in

```
int calculate(int, int);      // make this function known to the compiler

int main() {
    /* ... */
    result = calculate(m,n);  // okay: function is known
    /* ... */
}

int calculate(int n, int m)   // provide full function definition
{
    /* ... */
    return result;
}
```

Here, the declaration of `calculate()` may be in another file (a header file, say `calculate.h`) and the full definition of `calculate()` in yet another file (a source file, say, `calculate.cc`). In the latter case, you must make sure that the loader finds the correct function that is called from `main()`, i.e. you must link the object files together.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can only resolves names it is familiar with at a given point. The point where it needs to resolve your call to `calculate()` is before any mention of it in the code, hence the compiler isn't familiar with it at that point.

To solve this, you need to have `calculate()` declared before (above, in the code) the function in which you call it, which is your `main()` function.

Accomplish this by either:

1. Move the entire definition of `calculate()` so that it'll be above your `main()` -- could be in the same .cpp file or in an included header file.
2. Alternatively, just declare `calculate()` somewhere above `main()` -- could be in the same .cpp file or in an included header file -- and leave the definition where it is now.